# Phase shift/angle between input voltage and current rectifier and LC filter

Tags: filter, rectifier, passive-networks, phase

[image]

What is the phase shift approximately between Voltage and current in the attached picture?

Comment: Homework questions without any attempt to solve it is discouraged/not allowed here. Please add your proposed solution.

Comment: I think around 90 degrees.

Comment: Tested with multisim. Appears almost 90 degrees. Still need third/forth/fiftth ... party confirmation. thanks

Comment: Add that to your question, along with your simulation results.

Comment: simulation results give 90 degrees. That is far enough. your answer is ? Will send picture of naked Woman/Man as a gift :). I have the simulation results. Need confirmation from more experienced ...

Comment: No. Calculate Z for the inductor and capacitor respectively and compare them to the resistor. That should give you a crude approximation of the phase but you need to simulate it since it gets much worse with top wave rectification.

Comment: put the reply into other answer

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather meaningless question, because with the rectifier, the capacitor charges up to a (nearly) constant voltage. Note that the R-C time constant following the rectifier is 10s, which is a couple of orders of magnitude greater than the input (half-)period. The steady-state current waveform is highly distorted (a series of narrow pulses) and does not look at all like a phase-shifted version of the voltage waveform.

There still is a tiny 50-Hz component of the current waveform (in addition to all of the harmonics). Ignoring the inductor, this component is in-phase (phase shift of 0°) with the voltage waveform. When you add the inductor, the pulses are delayed slightly, introducing a tiny phase shift in the 50 Hz component.

Comment: Thank you. And in case of 50 Ohm (not 1000 Ohm) resistor , I suppose the phase shift will be signifficantly larger ?

Comment: No, not really. The magnitude of the current pulses will be increased, but their timing -- and the inductor's effect on them -- will not be significantly different. You won't see any significant effect from reducing the resistance until you get down to around 1 ohm, which is capable of discharging the capacitor by more than half between half-cycles.

Answer (score -1):

For XL (inductor) = 31 Ohm approx
For Xc (capacitor) = less than Ohm

According simulation phase angle/shift between Us and Is is close to 90 degrees.

Also, the input frequency is 50Hz

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @jbord39 People most likely don't see it as an answer, which it isn't. I asked Zapadug to calculate Z, but that's just so we can compare the magnitude of impedances to understand why and guesstimate the answer. That capacitor would have been a short at 50 Hz without the bridge rectifier but now we need to consider the top wave rectification. Also, Xl is > R, so the resistor plays a very small role but we are not at 90 degrees

Comment: Xl is < R actually.  R= 1000 Ohm Xl is 30 Ohm at 50 Hz